# Difficulty in creating and handling a complex post type

Tags: posts

I would like to create a restaurant guide for a client.

The restaurants of course are divided in various categories (and many of those may belong to two or more categories). This is the easy part.

The tricky one, I do not know how to handle is the following: A restaurant has a photo and some description. A restaurant may (or may not) have a section dedicated to its' Menu. A restaurant may (or may not) have a section of Offers. A resturant may (or may not) have photos.

In the home page there are (among the other sections) two sections relative to New Menus and New Offers. If a restaurant changes its' menu or offer (or both) its' photo and details have to appear for the New Menus and its' photo and the kind of Offer for the New Offers.

Does anyone have any idea on how can I approach it?

I have in mind a solution but it is very bulky. My solution is to create a Category with the restaurant's name, then for each restaurant's section to create a custom post type assigning as category the name of the restaurant and then in the Post page, relative to the restaurant, assemble the post with the various custom post types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already, I'd suggest looking at the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin. They have two custom fields that might help a lot in this situation: Post Object and Relationship. Browse all their [custom fields here](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/).

What these allow you to do, essentially (insofar as my understanding goes...), is to link one post (a restaurant, let's say) to another post(s): menu, offerings, etc. That alone, along with its many other custom fields, would take care of a lot of the bloat you're afraid of. Not to mention, it'd be a lot easier this way to have separate loops on your homepage for new offerings and new menus, as they'd already be their own custom post type.